# Bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to compile a latex document using bibtex.

Can anyone suggest a bibliography style which compiles  journal articles as

> Author Surname, Initials. Title of the article, \it{Name of Journal}, {\bf Volume No.} (Issue No.), pages, Year.

Books compiled as

> Author Surname, Initials. \it {Title}, Publisher, Place of Publication, Year.

Comment: Quite hard to tell, at least for me. Try out the different styles already available, or use `custombib` to generate your own bibliographystyle. Using `biblatex`, you can use simple LaTeX macros. It is quite time consuming to deal with customized bibliographies, no matter which way you go.

Comment: The documentation of `biblatex` has quite a few samples of different possible styles.

Comment: Does your bib file contain only entries of type `@article` and `@book`? If it contains other entry types, how should they be formatted?

Comment: @Mico 

conference_proceedings should be formatted as this example
 

Randell,  D.  A.,  Cui,  Z.,  &  Cohn,  A.  A  spatial  logic  based  on  regions  and  connection,  in  Principles  of 
Knowledge Representation and Reasoning (KR’ 92), Morgan Kaufmann, San Mateo, California, 165­176.

Comment: As @Johannes_B has already noted, probably the most straightforward path you can take is to run the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/), to create a bibliography style file from scratch. The utility is entirely menu-driven and the code it produces is of very high quality. Running the utility and answering the multiple-choice questions shouldn't take more than ten to fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with `memoir` class an the options for `biblatex` for your request are are here down. I hope that helps you.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=inputenc, %-ibid
 hyperref=true,backref=true,maxnames=4,firstinits=true,uniquename=true]{biblatex}
 \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% otherwise, "p." or "pp." is added by the authoryear style

\bibliography{Your biblio}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think this fully answers the question. For one thing, If I remember correctly, the `authoryear` style does not print volume numbers in bold. (The rest may be correct, I cannot remember.) I also think that it is recommended to use `\addbibresource{filename.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{filename}` with `biblatex`.